# Android: Identify that phone is connected to a guest network over wifi

Tags: android, android-wifi

Is it possible to tell if the phone is connected to a wi-fi network without actually being logged in to it.

I want to be able to direct users to the browser if a that is the case.

My lame tries included trying to ping a server and if the server is reachable I am on a "properly" setup wi-fi network.

Anyone that has any bright ideas?

Comment: The question should really be if the phone is connected to a guest network without ...

Answer (score 0):

You could check to which SSID the phone is connected via the [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html). Everything else if the user has logged in to a captiv portal is a network issuse. You could ask depending on the SSID the auth server for the login status.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally called a "captive portal" situation. It is often seen on guest networks, but some guest networks do not feature a captive portal.

ConnectivityManager cm =context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
boolean captivePortal = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNw).hasCapability(
                    NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED));